# Mocking Interfaces in PHP Unit

Tags: php, unit-testing

I am not sure what I am doing wrong/. I get the error:

```
Configuration read from /vagrant/freya-component-pagebuilder/phpunit.xml

....E........

Time: 50 seconds, Memory: 83.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) PageSectionTest::testBuildSectionsNotNull
Argument 3 passed to Freya\Component\PageBuilder\PageSection\PageSection::buildSections() must be an instance of Freya\Component\PageBuilder\FieldHandler\IFieldHandler, instance of Mock_IFieldHandler_4f9ceb0e given, called in /vagrant/freya-component
-pagebuilder/tests/PageSectionTest.php on line 58 and defined

/vagrant/freya-component-pagebuilder/Freya/Component/PageBuilder/PageSection/PageSection.php:24
/vagrant/freya-component-pagebuilder/tests/PageSectionTest.php:58
/usr/local/bin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:151
/usr/local/bin/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:103

FAILURES!
Tests: 13, Assertions: 4, Errors: 1.

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

I mean it seems pretty obvious but my test is mocking the Interface ....

```
public function testBuildSectionsNotNull() {
    $stub = $this->getMockBuilder('IFieldHandler')
                 ->setMethods(array('getFields'))
                 ->getMock();

    $stub->method('getFields')
         ->with(111)
         ->willReturn(array('something' => 'something else'));

    $sections = $this->pageSectionClassInstance->buildSections($this->parentPage, 'child_pages', $stub, '_default_partial');
    $this->assertNotEmpty($section);
}
```

It knows this exists because:

```
use Freya\Component\PageBuilder\PageSection\PageSection;
use Freya\Component\PageBuilder\FieldHandler\IFieldHandler;
use Freya\Factory\Pattern;

class PageSectionTest extends WP_UnitTestCase { ... }
```

I tried mocking the class that implements the Interface but that didnt work either. Argument three is the `$stub`. So my question is: **Why doesn't this work? I am mocking an interface ... The class exists and is seen ..**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the fully-qualified name to `$this->getMockBuilder()`. In your example you need to pass the string `'Freya\Component\PageBuilder\FieldHandler\IFieldHandler'`.

If you're using PHP 5.5 or later, you can also use the `::class` magic constant instead of a string. In your example it would be `IFieldHandler::class`.